# json_decode: 'Syntax error' for valid JSON from HEREDOC string

Tags: php, json, heredoc

I have the JSON code below. According to [one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) or [two](https://jsonlint.com/) JSON validators it is valid JSON.

```json
{
  "patterns": {
    "email": "/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
    "phone": "/(?:(?:\\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?|\\+)44\\)?[\\s-]?(?:\\(?0\\)?[\\s-]?)?)|(?:\\(?0))(?:(?:\\d{5}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4,5})|(?:\\d{4}\\)?[\\s-]?(?:\\d{5}|\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3}))|(?:\\d{3}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3,4})|(?:\\d{2}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4}[\\s-]?\\d{4}))(?:[\\s-]?(?:x|ext\\.?|\\#)\\d{3,4})?/"
  }
}
```

However, when I try to decode using in PHP using the `json_decode` function I get a 'Syntax Error'. Here's my PHP code:

```php
const JSON_CONFIG = <<<JSON
{
  "patterns": {
    "email": "/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
    "phone": "/(?:(?:\\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?|\\+)44\\)?[\\s-]?(?:\\(?0\\)?[\\s-]?)?)|(?:\\(?0))(?:(?:\\d{5}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4,5})|(?:\\d{4}\\)?[\\s-]?(?:\\d{5}|\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3}))|(?:\\d{3}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3,4})|(?:\\d{2}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4}[\\s-]?\\d{4}))(?:[\\s-]?(?:x|ext\\.?|\\#)\\d{3,4})?/"
  }
}
JSON;

$config = json_decode(mb_convert_encoding(JSON_CONFIG, "UTF-8"), true); // Tried called trim but it made no difference
echo 'json_last_error_msg() => ' . json_last_error_msg() . PHP_EOL;
print_r($config); // Doesn't get to run
```

Try for yourself: https://repl.it/@DanStevens/PHP-jsondecode-Syntax-Error

Any ideas what `json_decode` isn't liking this valid JSON? Is it related to the use of HEREDOC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslashes are acting as PHP escape sequences, not JSON escape sequences.  To prevent PHP escaping, surround your heredoc start token in single quotes:

```
const JSON_CONFIG = <<<'JSON'
{
  "patterns": {
    "email": "/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
    "phone": "/(?:(?:\\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?|\\+)44\\)?[\\s-]?(?:\\(?0\\)?[\\s-]?)?)|(?:\\(?0))(?:(?:\\d{5}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4,5})|(?:\\d{4}\\)?[\\s-]?(?:\\d{5}|\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3}))|(?:\\d{3}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3,4})|(?:\\d{2}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4}[\\s-]?\\d{4}))(?:[\\s-]?(?:x|ext\\.?|\\#)\\d{3,4})?/"
  }
}
JSON;

var_dump(JSON_CONFIG);
echo PHP_EOL;

$config = json_decode(mb_convert_encoding(JSON_CONFIG, "UTF-8"), true); // Tried called trim but it made no difference
echo 'json_last_error_msg() => ' . json_last_error_msg() . PHP_EOL;
echo 'json_last_error() => ' . json_last_error() . PHP_EOL;
print_r($config);
```

Repl: https://repl.it/repls/AmusedOvercookedEmbed

Comment: Changing the HEREDOC statement from `<<<JSON` to `<<<'JSON'` did the trick! Thanks! https://repl.it/@DanStevens/PHP-jsondecode-Syntax-Error-fixed